# Orientdb quote in SQL query

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I found strange behaviour of SQL query in OrientDB Studio (also it repeated in REST protocol).

My server version is 2.2.5

Data in my class:

```
select * from name
```

Result:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#25:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "name",
            "surname": "foo surname",
            "name": "foo name"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#26:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "name",
            "surname": "bar surname",
            "name": "bar name"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#27:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "name",
            "surname": "O'brien",
            "name": "baz"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.069 sec. Returned 3 record(s)"
 }
```

Where properties surname and name are text fields.

I create some SQL queries in Studio:

```
select * from name WHERE surname='O\'brien'
```

Result:

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#27:0",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "name",
        "surname": "O'brien",
        "name": "baz"
       }
   ],
"notification": "Query executed in 0.016 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
```

}

Works good.

Next:

```
select * from name WHERE NOT (surname='O\'brien')
```

Result:

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#25:0",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "name",
        "surname": "foo surname",
        "name": "foo name"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#26:0",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "name",
        "surname": "bar surname",
        "name": "bar name"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#27:0",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "name",
        "surname": "O'brien",
        "name": "baz"
    }
],
"notification": "Query executed in 0.015 sec. Returned 3 record(s)"
```

}

In this case I obtained unexpected third result.

Next:

```
select * from name WHERE (NOT (surname='bar surname'))
```

Result:

```
{
   "result": [
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#25:0",
           "@version": 1,
           "@class": "name",
           "surname": "foo surname",
           "name": "foo name"
        },
        {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#27:0",
           "@version": 1,
           "@class": "name",
           "surname": "O'brien",
           "name": "baz"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.017 sec. Returned 2 record(s)"
}
```

Looks fine.

Next:

```
select * from name WHERE (NOT (surname='O\'brien'))
```

Result:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Next:

```
select * from name WHERE (surname='O\'brien')
```

Result:

```
Empty result
```

My question - it is bug, or I do something wrong?

These queries are parts of query builder, so I need understand how works in OrientDB parentheses.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try it in the latest version? If it persists you can open an issue on github.

Comment: Yes, I reproduced it in the 2.2.12-SNAPSHOT, issue on github - https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6786

Answer (score 0):

> ODB ver2.2.12

Use different types of quote.

my data:

`select from V`

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#9:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "V",
            "name": "O'Brian"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#10:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "V",
            "name": "Pippo"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.013 sec. Returned 2 record(s)"
}
```

`select from V where NOT (name = "O'Brian")`

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#10:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "V",
            "name": "Pippo"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.023 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but if I want use double quote in query, it still doesn't work:

Comment: select * from foo where NOT (name="Bar\"Baz")